# Will node end the process if main thread finished with async function executing?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry if this has been answered, it seems like it would be already, but I was not able to find an exact answer. Let's say, we have a program similar to this:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

...

listOfFiles.forEach(veryLargeFile => fs.copyFile(veryLargeFile, path.join(newLocation, veryLargeFile));
```

In the example above, I used `fs.copyFile` but it can be any long-running async operation. Am I guaranteed that node process will wait for all files to copy before terminating the process, or do I need to explicitly `await` for it? I'm aware that node will not wait for pending promises, but I'm not sure if this falls into the same category.

Comment: Did you try this? It's actually a good question, but it feels like it can easily be answered.

Comment: You're right, this was simple enough to answer myself (I didn't think of it at first). The answer is that the process will not end until all async functions return. The above code is safe.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by another commenter, this was simple enough to test myself. I generated a few large (~1GB) files using `dd` and then tested it with a script similar to the one above:

```
let fs = require("fs");
let path = require("path");

let oldLocation = "./input/";
let newLocation = "./output/";
let inputfiles = fs.readdirSync(oldLocation);
inputfiles.forEach(veryLargeFile =>
  fs.copyFile(
    path.join(oldLocation, veryLargeFile),
    path.join(newLocation, veryLargeFile),
    err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("completed");
    }
  )
);
```

It does look like the main thread does indeed wait until all async logic is resolved before terminating so the above code is safe without explicitly blocking the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Async processes (all of them) are delegated to be managed by event loop and them can be executed in different threads. Does not matter if them are promises or callbacks.